# chart.js does not load table data

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, charts

I would like to help, I'm willing to display the table data generated from my webservice on a graph (with two fields product name and quantity), but I think my code for the chart is wrong.
The table is working properly, only the chart that is in error.

My FrontEnd

```
var app = angular.module('appCompras', []);

app.controller('comprasCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    var link = "http://localhost:58593/WebService.asmx"

    var url = link + "/" + "ListarQuinzeCompras";

    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {

        $scope.names = data;


        var randomScalingFactor = function () { return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) };

        var barChartData = {
            labels: [$scope.names.Nome],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [$scope.names.Quantidade]
                },
            ]

        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    })


});
```

My WebService

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void ListarQuinzeCompras()
    {
        var SQL = new LibOrgm.SQL();
        var cn = new ADODB.Connection();

        try
        {
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            SQL.AbrirConexao(cn);

            var retorno = ComprasFO.ListarUltimasQuinzeCompras(cn);
            Context.Response.Write(SerializerFO.Serializador(retorno));
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Context.Response.Write(Ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            SQL.FecharConexao(cn);
        }
    }
```

My DataAccess class

```
using ADODB;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using LibOrgm;
 using System.Globalization;

 namespace WebApplication1.BI.Graficos.Compras
 {
    public class ComprasDA
    {
        public static ComprasBO GetCompras(int PkCompras, Connection cn)
        {
            var Compra = new ComprasBO();
            var RsCompra = new ADODB.Recordset();
            try
            {
                RsCompra.Open(String.Format("select * from Compras where PkCompras = {0}", PkCompras), cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                if (!RsCompra.EOF )
                {
                    Compra.PkCompras = int.Parse(RsCompra.Fields["PkCompras"].Value.ToString());
                    Compra.IdProduto = int.Parse(RsCompra.Fields["IdProduto"].Value.ToString());
                    Compra.Nome = RsCompra.Fields["Nome"].Value.ToString();
                    Compra.Quantidade = int.Parse(RsCompra.Fields["Quantidade"].Value.ToString());
                    Compra.DataCompra = DateTime.Parse(RsCompra.Fields["DataCompra"].Value.ToString()); 
                    //DateTime.ParseExact(RsCompra.Fields["DataCompra"].Value.ToString(), "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                      
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return Compra;
        }


        public static ComprasBO[] ListUltimos15(Connection cn)
        {
            var RsCompras = new Recordset();
            try
            {
                RsCompras.Open("SELECT TOP 15 PkCompras FROM Compras ORDER BY PkCompras DESC", cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                if (!RsCompras.EOF)
                {
                    var ListaCompras = new ComprasBO[RsCompras.RecordCount];
                    for (int i = 0; i < RsCompras.RecordCount; i++)
                    {
                        ListaCompras[i] = GetCompras(int.Parse(RsCompras.Fields[0].Value.ToString()), cn);
                        RsCompras.MoveNext();
                    }
                    RsCompras.Close();
                    return ListaCompras;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return new ComprasBO[0];
        }
    }
}
```

My class ComprasBO

```
public class ComprasBO
    {
        public int PkCompras { get; set; }
        public int IdProduto { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCompra { get; set; }
    }
```

My FunctionObject

```
 public static ComprasBO[] ListarUltimasQuinzeCompras(ADODB.Connection cn)
        {
            try
            {
                return ComprasDA.ListUltimos15(cn);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

---

#### Solved

Solution of the problem

```
var app = angular.module('appCompras', []);

app.controller('comprasCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    var link = "http://localhost:58593/WebService.asmx"

    var url = link + "/" + "ListarQuinzeCompras";

    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {

        $scope.names = data;


        var randomScalingFactor = function () { return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) };

        Array.prototype.carregaDados = function (dados) {
            return this.map(function (obj) {
                return obj[dados];
            });
        };

        var barChartData = {
            labels: data.carregaDados('Nome'),
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: data.carregaDados('Quantidade')
                },
            ]

        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    })
```

});

Comment: Please remove `Solved` from your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two possible explanations that explains your problem.

**First explanation:**:

"data" and "$scope.names" exist but there isn't "$scope.data"

```
var barChartData = {
                labels: [$scope.data.Nome],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data: [$cope.data.Quantidade]
                    },
                ]

            }
```

**Second explanation:**:

Your code renders your chart when the page is loaded, but your ajax call may not return anything yet, your variable "barChartData" could be "undefined".

One way to resolve your prolem would be to execute the rendering in the success function.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('appCompras', []);

    app.controller('comprasCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        var link = "http://localhost:58593/WebService.asmx"

        var url = link + "/" + "ListarQuinzeCompras";

        $http.get(url).success(function (data) {

            $scope.names = data;


            var randomScalingFactor = function () { return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) };

            var barChartData = {
                labels: [$scope.data.Nome],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data: [$cope.data.Quantidade]
                    },
                ]

            }
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
                responsive: true
            });
        })


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, I put my backend up to see if it facilitates understanding. Thank you

Comment: Because "$scope.data" doesn't exist

Comment: It is true! But even I remove $ scope, leaving only the data.nome still not working.

Comment: Because "data" is an array of "ComprasBO", not an object :)

Comment: That! My table displays the data correctly, only the chart that displays nothing: /

Comment: Could you update the description of your question with the change you've made plz